# How to use for loop for nested arrays instead of using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, nested-loops

How to create a new list with all user information, but add "!" to the end of each items they own.I know to solve this with map. But i'm finding it hard as a beginner to do this with a for loop. Here is the code. I would really appreciate the help.

```
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
```

Comment: I found it a bit hard to follow what you mean by 'add "!" to the end of each item they own'. Maybe you could add a small example of the desired state of your object to the question, to better point out what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the elements using `for ... of`, then loop over the items for the object with an index-based `for` loop to update it.

```js
const array = [ { username: "john", team: "red", score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"] }, { username: "becky", team: "blue", score: 10, items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"] }, { username: "susy", team: "red", score: 55, items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"] }, { username: "tyson", team: "green", score: 1, items: ["book", "pen"] },];
for(const {items} of array){
  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) items[i] += '!';
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return a new array and not mutate the original you need to clone each nested object (in this case each object, and then each 'items' array).

Here using nested [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops in conjunction with [`Array#entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) to access the index and value. Each object and its nested `items` array is cloned using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) before updating the item values and then pushing the objects to the `copy` array.

```js
const array = [{ username: "john", team: "red", score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"] }, { username: "becky", team: "blue", score: 10, items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"] }, { username: "susy", team: "red", score: 55, items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"] }, { username: "tyson", team: "green", score: 1, items: ["book", "pen"] },];

const copy = [];

for (const object of array) {
  const objectCopy = { ...object, items: [...object.items] }
  for (const [i, string] of objectCopy.items.entries()) {
    objectCopy.items[i] = string + '!'
  }
  copy.push(objectCopy)
}

console.log(copy);
```

If you simply want to mutate the original array you can use nested [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) loops, here using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to isolate the `items` array in the outer loop before iterating it in the inner loop.

```js
const array = [{ username: "john", team: "red", score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"] }, { username: "becky", team: "blue", score: 10, items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"] }, { username: "susy", team: "red", score: 55, items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"] }, { username: "tyson", team: "green", score: 1, items: ["book", "pen"] },];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const { items } = array[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    items[j] += '!';
  }
}

console.log(array);
```